# Sobald wie/als möglich

Tags: word-usage

A common sentence (e.g. on an answering machine) is:

```
Ich rufe Sie sobald wie/als möglich zurück
```

What's the correct use here? `wie` sounds correct to me, but I've heard `als` pretty often too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*, both *„wie“* and *„als“* may be used after *„so bald“.* Both are correct; however, *„so bald wie“* is used more frequently.

> *Schreibe so bald wie möglich*
>
> *Schreibe so bald als möglich* (less frequently)

*Duden* recommends using *„so bald wie möglich“.*

In my opinion, *„so bald als möglich“* sounds terrible and wrong.

Comment: Though both are possible you'd usually say *so bald wie*. *so ... wie* indicates an equality. *als* would rather be used in a comparison that doesn't express equality (for example *er ist größer als* or *ruf nicht später an als nötig*).

Comment: Seht bitte meinen Kommentar zu Matthias' Antwort.

Comment: To me, *so bald **als** möglich* sounds a bit old fashioned, but neither wrong nor terrible.

Answer (score 9):

Both versions are correct. Using "wie" is more common, but "als" is possible, too.

References: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sobald) and [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2010/03/09/so-schnell-wie-moglich-so-schnell-als-moglich/)

The canoo page points out that the version with "wie" matches the general rule to use "wie" in comparisons that express equality.

Comment: Historisch waren "als" und "wie" aber gleichbedeutend. Bei "so groß wie" und "größer als" gibt es heute einen starken Unterschied, "Ich bin verkleidet als Räuber Hotzenplotz" oder "er riecht, als habe er 3 Wochen nicht gebadet" wird das "als" aber auch wie ein "wie" verwendet und ein "wie" klänge falsch oder wäre falsch (verkleidet wie Räuber Hotzenplotz => dieser ist selbst verkleidet).